# UTM-метки значения полей пустые

Tags: php, cookie

HTML код:

```
<form action="form/sender.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="TITLE" value="DANI. Заказ комплектующих" style="width: 75%;">
    <input type="hidden" name="UF_CRM_1464947673" value="426">
    <input type="hidden" name="SOURCE_ID" value="11">
    <input type="hidden" name="ASSIGNED_BY_NAME" value="2135">
    <input class="name" name="name" type="text" required placeholder="Имя">
    <input class="phone" name="phone" type="text" required placeholder="Телефон">
    <input type="hidden" name="utm_campaign" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['utm_campaign']) ? $_GET['utm_campaign'] : '' ;?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="utm_medium" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['utm_medium']) ? $_GET['utm_medium'] : '' ;?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="utm_source" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['utm_source']) ? $_GET['utm_source'] : '' ;?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="utm_content" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['utm_content']) ? $_GET['utm_content'] : '' ;?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="utm_term" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['utm_term']) ? $_GET['utm_term'] : '' ;?>" />
    <button type="submit">ОТПРАВИТЬ</button>
    <div style="font-size: 9px;margin-top: -20px;color: #636363;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="tandc" id="tandc" value="true" style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;margin-top: 0px;margin-right: 10px;width: 13px !important;" checked required><label for="tandc" style="display: inline-block; width: 90%;">Нажимая кнопку «Заказать звонок», я даю свое согласие на обработку моих персональных данных, в соответствии с Федеральным законом от 27.07.2006 года №152-ФЗ «О персональных данных», на условиях и для целей, определенных в Согласии на&nbsp;обработку персональных данных</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Обработчик:

```
$utm_source = trim($_POST["utm_source"]);
```

Прописываю `print_r($_POST)`.

Почему массив с UTM-метками пустой?

Comment: Потому что их нет в $_GET на момент формирования формы.

Comment: @ssn по какой ссылке запрошена страница? смотрите в адресной строке.

Answer (score 1):

UTM метки нужны чтобы отслеживать рекламную компанию по которой пришел пользователь. В вашем случае они берутся из GET, но что если посетитель пришел по ссылке из рекламе и прежде чем отправить форму - решил "побродить" по сайту? В таком случае метки уже будут утеряны.

Для того чтобы избежать этого, вам нужно на всех страницах сайта проверять - указаны ли UTM метки в адресной строке и если указаны - запоминать их, т.е.:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['utm_source']) || isset($_REQUEST['utm_campaign'])){
    unset($_SESSION['utm']);
    $_SESSION['utm']['utm_source'] = $_REQUEST['utm_source'];
    $_SESSION['utm']['utm_campaign'] = $_REQUEST['utm_campaign'];
    $_SESSION['utm']['utm_medium'] = $_REQUEST['utm_medium'];
    $_SESSION['utm']['utm_term'] = $_REQUEST['utm_term'];
    $_SESSION['utm']['utm_content'] = $_REQUEST['utm_content'];
}
```

В таком случае у вас они будут сохраняться в сессиях (можете переделать под cookie, т.к. у вас метка cookie стоит). И тогда вам не нужно будет передавать их в форме - достаточно просто "вытянуть" необходимые значения из сессии при обработке отправленной формы. Например, вот так:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['utm'])){
    foreach ($_SESSION['utm'] as $name => $value){
        $queryData[$name] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: у меня пустые значения, вытягиваются?

Comment: Не знаю вытягиваются ли у вас пустые значения. Но если значения пустые - значит в даресной строке utm меток никогда и не было...или вы сделали что-то не так

Comment: @ssn Естественно пустые. У вас что хранится в переменной `$utm_campaign` готов поспорить что ничего, ибо вы путаете с `$queryData['utm_campaign']` Вы видимо вообще не понимаете что делает этот код, который я приложил? Откуда вы вообще взяли `$queryData[$utm_campaign]`?

Comment: @ssn Сделайте просто вывод `print_r($_SESSION)` где-нибудь. Просто для того чтобы смотреть что там вообще есть. если пусто - тогда вопрос уже в том в какое место вы запихнули код из первого примера - он должен быть в начале вывода КАЖДОЙ страницы

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!

Comment: Подскажите, можно  использовать код если сайт на Wordpress?

Comment: @ssn Wordpress на PHP? Да. Значит и код там использовать можно. Первый код - перед выводом каждой страницы, а второй - во время обработки отправленной формы. Для работы с конкретным плагином отправки форм - придется либо в плагине обработку формы править, либо код видоизменять под плагин, но это уже не ко мне вопрос. А так, если ответ правильный и решает ваш вопрос - отмечайте его как верный.

Comment: Сайт на WP. Как вы написали, я добавила первый код-перед выводом каждой страницы,сделала вывод print_r($_SESSION)- результат:Array ( [utm] => Array ( [utm_source] => YD [utm_campaign] => CShop_General_Falloimitatory_2_msk [utm_medium] => cpc [utm_term] => купить резиновый член [utm_content] => k50id|0100000010511835319_|cid|28988059|gid|2833386247|aid|4556152689|adp|no|pos|premium2|src|search_none|dvc|desktop|main )), а второй во время обработки отправленной формы, но опять пустые метки.